# How to find view fo storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

i am making an application for Ipad using in xcode single view application.In storyboard of application I have created many **view controller scene** for all module of application.I have  made a **view controller scene** as Home page, in which i have given the menu buttons  when ever I am tapping any button I wants to add **view controller scene** OR **view** of that module as a submodule of  **home page view**, **because I need to show manu on each module of application.**
please suggest me how to find view of modules & add it as a subview of home page view.

If i am not going right please suggest me right way to meet my requirement.

regards anupam

Comment: u need to know the present sub view only right?

Comment: present subview of all view controller scene , so that i can add these  subview as a subview of home page view.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Select your subviewController in storyboard
2. Select utility (for set viewcontroller properties) select identity inspector
   -> There is filed for class - set class name for viewcontroller like:  **Subview1ViewController**
   ->There is filed for storyboard Id - give the identifier/storyboard Id to viewcontroller as in my case **SubView1**.

   Now need to move on HomeViewController.m file,  where we get the the viewcontroller object from storyboard.

*MainStoryboard =  your storyboard name

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
 subView1Object = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubView1"];
[self.view addSubview:subView1Object.view];
```

:)
I want to add a image of storyboard for better understanding of how to give class name & identifier but due to some restriction i am not able to post image error I am facing is "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." :(  So I am new to Stackover flow so if you like anser please like and give me reputation :)